# Typescript generics type constraints and type compatibility

Tags: typescript, generics, events

I'm having an issue with generics to generalized an event handling class.

Here is some proto code to reproduce the issue:

```
interface Base { }
interface ClassOf<T extends Base> extends Function { new (...args: any[]): T; }
type Handler<T extends Base = Base> = (event: T) => Promise<any>;

export class Manager<T extends Base = Base> {

  public handlers: Map<string, Handler<T>> = new Map();

  go<E extends T>(first: ClassOf<E>, handler: Handler<E>): void {
    this.handlers.set(first.name, handler);
                                  ^^^^^^^
  }
}
```

Typescript compiler returns the following error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'Handler<E>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Handler<T>'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'E'.
      Type 'Base' is not assignable to type 'E'.
(parameter) handler: Handler<E>
```

Short than make the Handler function signature take "any", is there any way to hint at the compiler at T and E in this context are compatible ?

Are there other avenues to keep this class as generic as possible?

Any pointers appreciated!

-b

Comment: `handler` only accepts an argument of type `E`, which could be a subtype of `T`, so if TypeScript allowed you to store it in the `handlers` map, then it could be looked up and called with an argument that is a `T` and not an `E`.  Can you explain a little more about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to make a generic event handling class, where you can map event classes to handlers (functions that receives instance of the same class). The mapping is done on the class constructor name. I do understand the nature of your explanation but wonder how I could write the generic constraint in reverse for my handlers property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any way to hint at the compiler at T and E in this context are compatible

Compiler already knows that `T` and `E` are compatible because of `E extends T` constraint you have for `go` function. To be more precise, `E` is assignable to `T`.

But it does not make `Handler<E>` to be compatible with `Handler<T>`, because `E` and `T` are types for a handler argument. Suppose for example `E` is an object with two properties

```
type E = {firstName: string; lastName: string}
```

and `T` has only `firstName`:

```
type T = {firstName: string};
```

Suppose then you have a handler for `E` which expects to receive an object with two properties

```
function handlerForE(e: {firstName: string, lastName: string});
```

then you can't assign it to `Handler<T>` because it's possible to call `Handler<T>` with an object that has only one field which is present in `T` - `firstName`, and `Handler<E>` needs both.

Basically, type compatibility usually goes in certain direction, and placing a type in function argument position switches it's direction - if `E` is assignable to `T`, then `Handler<T>` is assignable to `Handler<E>` (because `Handler<T>` can just ignore the extra property), not the other way round.

But TypeScript compiler has an option to ignore such incompatibility for function types - if you turn off [`strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) it will consider functions compatible if their arguments are compatible one way or another, regardless of the direction.

Comment: TIL I learned about covariance and contravariance. Thank you this is precisely what I was looking for as an explanation...and with a compiler switch to boot! Thank you!

As a reference: [What are covariance and contravariance?](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: I did end up making the internal typing flexible with <any> as others in this thread have suggested. It seemed like the only way to work around the aforementioned fact without having to turn the compiler switch (strictFunctionTypes)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you'd like a `Manager` to keep track of the relationship between the name of classes and handlers for that class, inside its `handlers` property.  If not, then you can forget about `Manager` and `go` being generic, and just use `Handler<any>` everywhere.

If so, then it's not incredibly straightforward.  The problem is that every time you call `go()` and add a handler, you need to *change* the type of the `Manager` to reflect it.  Specifically, you want to narrow the type of `handlers`.  TypeScript doesn't support changing the type of an existing variable, so you can't do that directly.  You *can* use the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) so that a call to `go` returns a *new* `Manager` whose type is appropriately narrowed, like this:

```
export class Manager<M extends Record<keyof M, Handler<any>>> {

  constructor(public handlers: M) {
  }

  go<K extends string, E extends Base>(
    first: {
      name: K & (K extends keyof M ? never : K),
      new(...args: any[]): E
    },
    handler: Handler<E>
  ) {
    const handlers = Object.assign(
      { [first.name]: handler } as Record<K, Handler<E>>, 
      this.handlers
    );
    return new Manager(handlers);
  }

  static make(): Manager<{}> {
    return new Manager({});
  }

}
```

I've changed `handlers` from a `Map` to a regular object, since TypeScript is not really equipped to maintain distinct key/value types in a `Map` whereas it does for objects, and because if your key is just a `string` or string literal, a `Map` is probably overkill.

Then you could use it like this:

```
class Foo implements Base {
  // @ts-ignore: TypeScript doesn't realize that Foo.name is "Foo",
  // so we will force it here 
  static name: "Foo";
  foo: string = "foo";
}
const fooHandler: Handler<Foo> = (event: Foo) => fetch(event.foo);

class Bar implements Base {
  // @ts-ignore: TypeScript doesn't realize that Bar.name is "Bar", 
  // so we will force it here
  static name: "Bar";
  bar: string = "bar";
}
const barHandler: Handler<Bar> = (event: Bar) => fetch(event.bar);

const manager = Manager.make().go(Foo, fooHandler).go(Bar, barHandler);
manager.handlers.Foo // known to be Handler<Foo>
manager.handlers.Bar // known to be Handler<Bar>
```

That works... you can see that `manager.handlers` is strongly-typed enough to know that it has two members, `Foo`, and `Bar`, which correspond to handlers for the types `Foo` and `Bar`, respectively.

There are obviously tons of caveats here... one is that TypeScript doesn't know that a constructor's `name` property is anything but a `string`, and we need it to be narrower.  And you have to remember to use chaining.  And you get new `Manager` objects with each call to `go()` (which could be addressed by type assertions, which have their own caveats).

Anyway, the point is: you need something fairly involved to keep track of your handlers at the type level.  Unless you need it, you probably want to use `Handler<any>` and be done with it.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intent correctly, each value of your map is not truly a `Handler<T>` but a `Handler<the subclass of T indicated by the key>`.  Your best option may be to declare the map's value type as `Handler<any>`.